# View Details (all the Fields) when clicking on Select Button in Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

How can I get a view of all the fields in a new asp page when clicking on the Button "Select" in Gridview in a webform asp page. I think I have to create a function which will be called on  "OnClientClick". Here's my code. How could I perform this task? thank you very much in advance, best regards

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>


                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="SelectButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Select" Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>



                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For button click event try:

```
<asp:gridview id="NewGridView" 
    datasourceid="NewSqlDataSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="false"
    onrowcommand="NewGridView_RowCommand"
    runat="server">

    <columns>
      <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Button" 
        commandname="Select"
        headertext="Select People" 
        text="Select"/>
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>


void NewGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

if(e.CommandName=="Select")
{      
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);  

  GridViewRow selectedRow = NewGridView.Rows[index];
}
}
```

Or check link,

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx
```